# How to implement integration by parts?

Tags: replacement, placeholder

I have been trying to simplify integrand expressions using integration by parts, which schematically is given by $\theta(x)\nabla\phi(x)=-\phi(x)\nabla\theta(x)$. I think this can be done as a replacement rule, but I don't know the correct syntax. Here is an attempt

```
IntegrationByParts = # D[\[Phi][x], x] -> \[Phi][x] D[#, x]
```

Testing the rule with the expression $\phi^2(x)\nabla\phi(x)$:

```
\[Phi][x]^2 D[\[Phi][x], x] /. IntegrationByParts
```

simply returns the same expression. The expected result is $\phi^2(x)\nabla\phi(x)=-2\phi^2(x)\nabla\phi(x)$.

Comment: Note: `#` is short for `Slot[1]`, and only makes sense in *function* syntax (`&`) to specify a formal parameter. Rules, however, use patterns, like `_`, which is short for `Blank[]`. To keep track of the pattern name it, e.g. `a : patt`, in this case `a_` (which is short for `a : _`—which is actually short for an even longer expression :) ), and to be safe with keeping track of named patterns, use delayed rules `:>` instead of `->` (so as to avoid evaluating the right hand side until the rule is applied).

Comment: likewise, `x` and `\[Phi]` are also used as patterns, but as trivial ones: they only match the literal symbols `x` and `\[Phi]`. I'm not sure if this is intentional or if you want more generality—how generally do you hope to implement integration by parts? note that given an integrand there are many ways to divide it up into $\theta$ and $\phi'$, and you also need to take into consideration what happens on the boundary. so if you have unevaluated symbols like `\[Phi]` in your integrand it might be simpler, but if you have arbitrary expressions it will be more difficult.

Comment: Ultimately I'd love to have something that works in all generality that replace (something * \nabla (another thing)) to (-(another thing) * \nabla(something)), while neglecting any boundary terms. However, I understand that there are more than one ways to express the integrand and it is not clear which way is "simpler". So for the current purpose, I'd be satisfied with something more restricted, that replaces (something function of \phi(x)) * \nabla(\phi(x)) with literally the symbol `\[Phi]` and `x`.

Comment: oh, ok. the highly specific case is very doable! try `IntegrationByParts = (f_ D[\[Phi][x], x] :> -\[Phi][x] D[f, x])`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of answer:

> oh, ok. the highly specific case is very doable! try `IntegrationByParts = (f_ D[\[Phi][x], x] :> -\[Phi][x] D[f, x])` –
> thorimur Aug 9, 2021 at 8:30